# How can I add vector of pairs inside my class?

Tags: c++, class, vector

How can I add to my class a new vector of pairs ( `vector<pair<int, int> > v_vect` ) and give it values? So that after, I could use it inside my `.cpp` file and whenever I change the value of vector of pairs it stays there (I believe I should use reference to the “&” vector).

Comment: What have you already tried that is not working for you? Please [edit] your question to show your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

You have a vector of pairs : `vector<pair<int, int> > v_vect`

To add values, you can do : `v_vect.push_back(make_pair(x,y))`

To access values in a for loop : `

```
for (auto v : v_vect)
    {
        std::cout << v.first << " " << v.second << std::endl;
    }`
```

Assuming your vector is a private member of a class Test, I created this example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

        class Test
    {
    public:

        void addValue(int x, int y);
        void printvalue() const;

    private:
        std::vector<std::pair <int, int> > v_vect;

    };

    void Test::addValue(int x, int y)
    {
        v_vect.push_back(std::make_pair(x,y));
    }

    void Test::printvalue() const
    {
        for (auto v : v_vect)
        {
            std::cout << v.first << " " << v.second << std::endl;
        }
    }



    int main() {

        // Create your object of class Test, this object has its own v_vect
        Test object1;

        // adding your values 
        object1.addValue(1, 2); 
        object1.addValue(3, 4);

        // printing your vector
        object1.printvalue();

        while (1)
        { }

        return 0;
    }
```

Does it answer the question ?